# When to use which pronoun declination: mein, meiner, meine, meins, etc

Tags: declension, possessive-pronoun

I learned that a pronoun should take an ending in accordance with its gender, case, numerus, etc. whenever it refers to some noun in particular — ‘Das Auto ist meins’ for example.  So in the following poem, why is *mein* used instead of *meine*, even though it specifically refers to *die Jahre*?

> Mein sind die Jahre nicht, die mir die Zeit genommen.
>   Mein sind die Jahre nicht, die etwa möchten kommen.
>   Der Augenblick ist mein, und nehm' ich den in Acht,
>   so ist der mein, der Zeit und Ewigkeit gemacht.

Is a question of poetic licence or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: `Mein ist die Rache, spricht der Herr` (Dies irae).

Comment: »Mainz ist die Rache, spricht der Herr« ;)

Answer (score 8):

That’s archaic use of the construct *etw. ist mein/dein/sein* meaning *etw. gehört mir/dir/ihm*. It’s still used and common with objects and the — today — correct declension:

> Wem gehören die Schuhe? — Das sind meine.

… but is not so common for things, that can’t physically belong to a person like years, time or guilt. I’ll try a modern (not so poetic) “translation” of the poem:

> Mir gehören die Jahre nicht, die mir die Zeit genommen hat.
>   Mir gehören die Jahre nicht, die noch kommen mögen.
>   Mir gehört der Augenblick, und wenn ich den schätze,
>   dann gehört mir der, der Zeit und Ewigkeit erschuf.

---

In a less strict sense of posession the personal nouns are also used with year, time or guilt, of course. Some examples:

> Es ist meine Schuld, dass wir zu spät kommen.

I’m responsible for us being late.

> Das wird mein Jahr!

This year I’ll be successful and achieve everything I want.

> Die frühen Morgenstunden sind nicht seine Zeit.

Early morning is not the best time of the day for him.

Comment: So basically it's archaic to put no inflection and it's grammatically wrong today?  I'm not sure what most of your examples have to do with pronoun inflection.

Comment: @Brian Sorry for my late answer..and yes, that's right. The point is that the pronoun isn't inflected in `etw. ist mein` and that it means `etw. gehört mir`. My examples were supposed to show that immaterial nouns can also be used with personal pronouns.

Comment: The first sentence of your "modern translation" should have "haben", not "hat".

Comment: @user1205935 The subject of the relative clause is `die Zeit` and the auxiliary verb is therefore 3rd person singular, i.e. `hat`. The relative pronoun substituting `die Jahre` is the object of the relative clause. Cf. http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Funktion/Attribut/Relativ/index.html, third example.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I read it as "Mir gehören die Jahre nicht, die mir die Zeit genommen haben." I guess both are grammatically viable and the original poetical version is ambiguous, although I agree that your interpretation is nicer.

Comment: @user1205935 Ah, you're right. The original is ambigous, I haven't noticed.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to think of it as **my own** instead of **mine**.
That would make **mein** an adjective instead of a pronoun.

> Das Auto ist blau.
>
> Das Auto ist mein.

vs.

> Das Auto ist meins.

I can't really capture that in English because **mine** has also an adjective feel to it but the German **meine/s/r/n...** really feels like a pronoun.

> Das Auto ist meins.

is just short for

> Das Auto ist mein Auto.

Answer (score 1):

Note that we need to distinguish between the genitive case declension of the personal pronoun *ich*, i.e., *meiner*, and the various forms of the possessive pronoun *mein*.

For an actual usage of the genitive case, check some verbs that need a genitive object:

> Er erinnert sich meiner (=Er erinnert sich an mich). Er schämt sich meiner (=Er schämt sich wegen mir).

Still, your examples in the OP are rather poetic (and also my examples with genitive case may sound archaic/poetic to today’s everyday usage, but they might still be found in non-poetic elaborate texts, including newspapers).

Comment: Enlighten me; how does this help answering the question?